# Calculating the Elo rating if x beats y z % of the time

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

From 2015 - 2019 dancers competing at the Lindy Hope Championships were split into 4 levels of expertise.  The level four dancers beat the level three dancers on average 83% of the time.  If we were to automatically assume that level four dancers have a higher elo rating than level three dancers how much higher would that rating be.  The equation for calculating elo is:
$$
e = \frac{1}  {1 + 10^{(b-a)/400}}, 
$$
where $e$,  I think,  is the expected amount of time of victory. 
$b$ is the rating of the level 4 dancer.
$a$ is the rating of the level 4 dancer.

We know that $e$ must be $e= 0.83$ and $a=0$.  But I cannot figure out how to solve for $b$.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: So you just want to solve for $b$ in the expression? The first steps are to take the inverse of both sides, then subtract 1, and you're at
$$
\frac{1}{e}-1 = 10^{(b-a)/400}
$$
The next step is to take a logarithm ... Can you continue from here?

Comment: Don't use italics.  It's just a waste of time and it does not assist in understanding.  What do you think I can understand that e is a number if I don't italicize it?

Comment: No, I'm a dancer not a mathematician.

Comment: The standard way of writing variable names in mathematics is to use italics. See the second point here: https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ICTNS-On-the-use-of-italic-and-roman-fonts-for-symbols-in-scientific-text.pdf

Comment: It is Lindy Hop, not Hope.

Comment: I'm not arguing over what the standard for italics is, I'm arguing that the standard is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as follows

\begin{align}e &= \frac{1}  {1 + 10^{(b-a)/400}}\\
e\left(1+10^{(b-a)/400}\right)&=1\tag{1}\\
1+10^{(b-a)/400}&=\frac 1e\tag{2}\\
10^{(b-a)/400}&=\frac1e -1\tag{3}\\
\frac{b-a}{400}&=\log_{10}\left(\frac 1e -1\right)\tag{4}\\
b-a&=400\log_{10}\left(\frac 1e -1\right)\tag{5}\\
b&=400\log_{10}\left(\frac 1e -1\right)+a\tag{6}\end{align}

where the steps are

1. Multiply both sides by $e$
2. Divide both sides by $1+10^{(b-a)/400}$
3. Subtract $1$ from both sides
4. Take the logarithm of both sides. If we have $x=10^y$ then we can say that $\log_{10}(x)=y$. [Here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/logarithms.html) is a good introduction to logarithms
5. Multiply both sides by $400$
6. Add $a$ to both sides

You can then use [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+b%3D400*log_10%281%2F0.83+-1%29%2B0+) to solve the equation by filling in your values for $a$ and $e$ to find that $$b=-275.452$$

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that.