# Find the victory percentage of a player given other known values

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a set of chess players before the days of elo ranking.  Using your intuition you separate them into 4 levels of skill.  After several games you observe the following win-loss ratios:

The following stipulates how often each level wins against level 4:
level 3: 17%
level 2: 10%
level 1: 6%

The following stipulates how often each level wins against level 3
level 2: 31%
level 1: 22%

The following stipulates how often each level wins against level 2
level 1: 34%

If the results seem slightly counterintuitive it is because in real life the players simply declared their rank and those that did not declare a rank were for the most part bad, but some good players failed to declare their rank and were put into level 1 by default.  I'm going to go back and try to assign better rankings to the undeclared later.

Suppose player b when facing off against opponents of level 3 won 61% of the time or that he won 61 times and lost 39 times.  Had all those opponents been level 4 how many games would we expect him to have won and lost?

For players who face off only against opponents of level 2 we have two sets of data: how well they played against level 3 opponents and against level 4 opponents, so it seems to be more complicated.  Suppose player c when facing off against opponents of level 3 won 41% of the time or that he won 41 times and lost 59 times.  Suppose further when facing off against opponents of level 2 he won 59% of the time or that he won 59 times and lost 41 times.  Had all those opponents been level 4 how many games would we expect him to have won and lost?

My best stab at this problem is as follows:

We will assume that level 1 has an elo rating of 1000.  If level 2 beats level 1 66% of the time, then it follows with a hat-tip from what I learned from lioness99a here

[Calculating the Elo rating if x beats y z % of the time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3512208/calculating-the-elo-rating-if-x-beats-y-z-of-the-time)

and using the wolfram|alpha calculator

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+b%3D400*log_10%281%2F0.66+-1%29%2B0+

that level 2's elo rating would be 1115.  I'm not quite sure why b comes out negative but hopefully I'll find out soon enough.  Using the same method we can find out the other elo ratings:

level 3: 1253
level 4: 1528

I'm guessing that we can then guess player b's elo rating to be:

solve b=400*log_10(1/0.39 -1)+1253

which is 1330.

Then using the calculation from known elo ratings to the ratio of victory which is:

c = (higher elo - lower elo)/400

higher elo's victory % = 1/(1+10 exp c)

c = .00287218

higher elo's victory % = .49834

which seems off.  I would think it would be around .25.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question easier to read.

Comment: I don't know what MathJax is.

Comment: Check your calculation of $c$, I think you made a typo there. With lower elo = 1330 and higher elo = 1528, $c$ would be 
$$
c = \frac{1528 - 1330}{400} = 0.495
$$

Comment: MathJax is the way that we can typeset nice-looking math equations in this forum. If you click the link, all the explanations are there.

Comment: Ok, that comes to .2423 which is what is almost exactly what I thought the answer would be.  Does that mean that all my other calculations look sound?